# How a view is created in android?

Tags: android, android-view

I want to know how a `View` is created in `Android`. On a `View` object creation which functions are called?Initially `constructors` will be called.Next what? And so on.
If anybody know the sequence of functions called after object creation,Please reply me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) might help you better I guess.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Constructor** : to initialize variables

**2) onMeansure** : to prepare canvas , set Width and height

**3)OnDraw()** : to draw actual view .

now `onDraw()` will continuously be called after a particular interval which depends upon display/processor and UI eventsenter code here or on calling `invalidate()`